# How can I get ALL of my data to populate my dropdown?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, fetch-api

I am trying to display all the 'activities' data in my activities-dropdown. So far there is data displaying, just not ALL of the activities, only a few of them. It has something to do with my renderActivities loop, but I can't figure out what it is? Also, I would need to remove duplicate activities once I get that working. How do I do that?

Below is a sample of the JSON (there are 500 records) and my JS and HTML:

***JS:***

```
let parks = null
getParks()

function getParks(){
  fetch (url)
  .then (res => { return res.json() })
  .then (data => {
     parks = data
     console.log(parks)
     renderActivities()
  })
}

const acsDrop = document.getElementById('activities-dropdown')

acsDrop.length = 0

const acsDropDefault = document.createElement('option')
acsDropDefault.text = 'How do you wander?'
acsDropDefault.disabled = true

acsDrop.add(acsDropDefault)
acsDrop.selectedIndex = 0

function renderActivities() {  
    let option
    for (let i = 0; i < parks.data.length; i++) {
            option = document.createElement('option')
            option.text = parks.data[i].activities[0].name
            option.value = parks.data[i].activities[0].name
            acsDrop.append(option)
    }    
  }
```

***HTML:***

```
    <select id="activities-dropdown" name="activities" multiple="multiple"> 
    </select>       
    <br><br>
    <button id="submit">Let's Wander!</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>

    </div>
    <div id="park-results">

    </div>
  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

***JSON:***

```
  [ { "id"      : "77E0D7F0-1942-494A-ACE2-9004D2BDC59E"
    , "url"     : "https://www.nps.gov/abli/index.htm"
    , "fullName": "Abraham Lincoln Birthplace National Historical Park"
    , "parkCode": "abli"
    , "description": "For over a century people from around the world have come to rural Central Kentucky to honor the humble beginnings of our 16th president, Abraham Lincoln. His early life on Kentucky's frontier shaped his character and prepared him to lead the nation through Civil War. The country's first memorial to Lincoln, built with donations from young and old, enshrines the symbolic birthplace cabin."
    , "latitude" : "37.5858662"
    , "longitude": "-85.67330523"
    , "latLong"  : "lat:37.5858662, long:-85.67330523"
    , "activities": 
      [ { "id": "13A57703-BB1A-41A2-94B8-53B692EB7238", "name": "Astronomy"} 
      , { "id": "D37A0003-8317-4F04-8FB0-4CF0A272E195", "name": "Stargazing"} 
    }
```

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .  ~ 400 lines of code I doubt this can be considered minimal

Comment: I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a form element to simplify the JS code;
fetch commands are asynchronous...
have a look to https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-fetch-api/

I code that this way:

```js
const 
  myForm = document.forms['my-form']
, C_url  = 'https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?api_key=wSlcKl1LSOpHXf164FTShbQZC4cmu1VWTJiipnFk&limit=10' // limit=10 
  ;         
renderActivities() 

myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()        // disable form submit action
  //
  // any JS code...
  //
  }
async function getParks() 
  {
  try 
    {
    let res = await fetch(C_url);
    return await res.json();
    } 
  catch (error) 
    {
    console.log(error);
    }
  }
async function renderActivities() 
  {
  let parks = await getParks()

  myForm.activities.length = 0 // <select name="activities"  is a child of <form name="my-form"
  
  parks.data.forEach( (activity,index) =>
    {
    let name = activity.activities[0]?.name ?? null  // if activities[0] exist ?
    if (name)
      myForm.activities.add( new Option( name, index));
    })
  }
```

```css
select,
button {
  display : block;
  float   : left;
  clear   : left;
  margin  : .3em;
  }
select  {
  min-width : 8em;
  padding   : 0 .3em;
  }
```

```html
<form name="my-form" action="">
  <select name="activities" multiple ></select>
 
  <button type="submit">Let's Wander!</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```